# Workflow and Field Update to Standard, Required Field

Tags: workflow, picklist, field-update, required-field, contracts

On the Standard Contract Object, I am trying to make a default picklist value for Status upon Contract record creation. When I use a workflow and field update, the field doesn't get updated in the Edit screen, and unfortunately cannot progress to create the actual record as it is required. Therefore, I cannot make it so the user does NOT action the Status field, nor can I have it populate with the default once someone clicks "New" contract. If this is unclear, I will elaborate without issue.

Optimally, I want to be able to populate the Contract Status field with a default picklist value. I know I cannot choose a default value for a standard field, and that is why I've attempted to resort to a Workflow and Field Update. Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" solution would be to hack all the links to create a NEW record of that object to include a default value in the Record name.

For example, the link below will create a new account with "1234" in the account name. This would make the field "not required" (at least users won't have to enter a value) and then the WFR could update it upon save.

https://login.salesforce.com/001/e?retURL=%2F001%2Fo&acc2=1234

To get your link, simply go to the object, click on NEW, and ammend "&acc2=1234" at the end of the URL and that field will auto populate.

Comment: Prabhat, can you please tell me how to set it for Contract Status with our Contract Record, as we have to choose Record Type first. Below is our "New" button link. Thank you.

https://na16.salesforce.com/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Contract&retURL=%2F800%2Fo&save_new_url=%2F800%2Fe%3FretURL%3D%252F800%252Fo

Comment: Link doesn't work.

Comment: Prabhat,

Please see link of you continuing to waste time. Please give me a good link, rather than direct me to Google a URL.

http://imgur.com/qx9MIuW

Comment: Sorry i am answering throgh mobile.I don't know why you are unable to open this. I can open this in my browser. Please Google sales force URL hacking.

Comment: Prabhat,

Thank you. I got it.